# How to add listviewitems to an array when the check can be one or more items in a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, linq, any

Is there anyway to remove the three conditionals and use the one the problem is i can have one or more array lengths dependent on how many times the string can be split by a space.

```
            if (array.Length == 1)
            {
                list = FamilyDataItems.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                        .Where(x => x.SubItems
                        .Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                        .Any(y => y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[0])))
                        .ToArray();
            }
            else if (array.Length == 2)
            {
                list = FamilyDataItems.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                        .Where(x => x.SubItems
                        .Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                        .Any(y => y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[0]) 
                            && y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[1])))
                        .ToArray();
            }
            else if (array.Length > 2)
            {
                list = FamilyDataItems.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                        .Where(x => x.SubItems
                        .Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                        .Any(y => y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[0]) 
                            && y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[1]) 
                            && y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[2])))
                        .ToArray();
            }
```

Comment: Why not go opposite and do `array.Contains(y.Text.ToLowerInvariant());`? Then it doesn't matter how many items are in `array`.

Comment: `var list = lv.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(x => x.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>().Any(y => array.Contains(x.Text, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));`

Comment: I have tried the above answers, the problem is the array has shorter bits of text, that need to be found by the listview items. For example. the array has {"door", "double"} and the listviewitem string has doors_doubled-action, so i need to check if the lvi has in it both the door AND double. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment above, yes the comments suggestions won't get what you need. I think the following will.

If a `SubItem` should contain any word from the array:

```cs
void Caller()
{
    foreach (var item in yourListView.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>())
        item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;

    var array = new[] { "door", "double" };
    var list = yourListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        .Where(x => x.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
        .Any(y => array
        .Any(z => y.Text.IndexOf(z, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)));

    foreach (var item in list)
        item.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Or if a `SubItem` should contain all the words of the array:

```cs
void Caller()
{
    foreach (var item in yourListView.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>())
        item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;

    var array = new[] { "door", "double" };
    var list = yourListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        .Where(x => x.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
        .Any(y => array
        .All(z => y.Text.IndexOf(z, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)));

    foreach (var item in list)
        item.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I used provided by DR.Null as it was smaller and on stopwatch tests for 4K items with 256bit bmp images it was around 6 secs. The only code I changes was  yourListView.Items to my stored listviewitems array.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this -

```
list = FamilyDataItems.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                        .Where(
    (array.Length == 1 && x => x.SubItems
                        .Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                        .Any(y => y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[0]))) 
|| (array.Length == 2 && x => x.SubItems
                        .Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                        .Any(y => y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[0]) 
                            && y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[1]))) 
|| (array.Length > 2 && x => x.SubItems
                        .Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                        .Any(y => y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[0]) 
                            && y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[1]) 
                            && y.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(array[2]))))
).ToArray();
```

HTH and I didn't miss any parentheses

Comment: thanx Rajeev it is certainly more compact, than mine.

Comment: Nice to know Frank, could you please accept this as answer, if it helped you?

Comment: Thanx again Rajeev, Doctor Null got the banner this time!